# Media not found on internal storage

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have some old conversations where I have the messages, but the media files are no longer on my phone. I found some videos and photos on google photos with the original names, like "VID_20180908_WA00005.mp4". I downloaded it, changed the timestamp so it matches the original timestamp and copied it to WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/. But the video does not play and it gives me this error. What can I do to make whatsapp accept my video file as the original one?